# Javascript: Write a function that takes in an array, and then returns an array with only unique numbers, only arrays removed

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, key

Write a function that takes in a list and returns a list with all of the duplicates removed (list will only have unique numbers).

Here's what I have so far:

```
       var lista = [1,4,5,1,1,3,5,6,4,4,3];

      function dupRemove (lista) {
           //Sort the array in case it isn't sorted
           lista.sort();
           //Object to store duplicates and unique numbers
           var listNumbers = {
             "Duplicate Numbers": [],
             "Unique Numbers": []
           };
           for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
             //check if it is not equal to the index of the array before it and after. if it isn't, that means its unique, push it in the uniques array.
             if (lista[i] !== lista[i-1] && lista[i] !== lista[i+1]) {
               listNumbers["Unique Numbers"].push(lista[i]);
             } else {
               listNumbers["Duplicate Numbers"].push(lista[i]);
             }
           }
           return listNumbers;
         }
```

Currently, my solution returns an object with keys with the values of "Duplicates": 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 and "Uniques": 6.

How do I remove the duplicates from duplicates and then join these two keys into a single array?

Thank you.

Comment: You were answered an hour ago. It would be helpful if you did not remove your previous question.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to repost it better after reexamining the question and realizing I misunderstood it.

Comment: Try to evaluate your code manually: for example, evaluate the loop body line by line when `i = 0`.

Comment: The `.sort()` function by default sorts the array values as **strings**, not numbers. The value `10` will be considered less than `5`.

Comment: @zerkms Oh I guess you're right; like values would end up next to each other one way or the other :)

Answer (score 1):

that answer is seriously over -engineered- all you need to to is push all values into a new array if they are not already in it.

```
function=removeDups()
{
   var lista = [1,4,5,1,1,3,5,6,4,4,3];
   var uniqueValues=[];
   var duplicateValues=[];
   for(i=0;i<lista.length;i++)
     {
       if(uniqueValues.indexof(lista[i] == -1){uniqueValues.push(lista[i]}else{duplicateValues.push(lista[i]}
     }
}
```

Comment: This works but it would be more efficient to keep track of already-seen values as object properties than as values in an array.

Comment: @Pointy ... if only the value type is serialisable to a string easily

Comment: @zerkms yes yes that's true - in ES2015 you could use a Set

Comment: answer amended to push duplicate values into their own array as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the default filter method that is on all Arrays

You don't need the sort function either. If the item is already found using the indexOf method it will not be added to the newly returned array created by the filter method

```js
var list = [1,4,5,1,1,3,5,6,4,4,3];

function removeDup (arr) {
   return arr.filter(function(item, pos) {
      return arr.indexOf(item) == pos;
 })
}

var sortedList = removeDup(list).sort(function(a,b){
  return  a - b
})

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent = sortedList
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a non elegant solution but it gives you the two arrays: one with the duplicate values and one with the unique ones. Since you cannot rely on .sort() you can just count things.

Function checkList will give you back those two arrays.

```
var list = [1,4,5,1,1,3,5,6,4,4,3];

console.log(checkList(list));

function checkList(list) {
    var uniques = []; // will be [6]
    var dups = []; // will be [1, 4, 5, 3]
    var checked = []; // save what you have already checked so far

    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(notChecked(list[i], checked)) {
            checked.push(list[i]);
            if(count(list[i], list) > 1) {
                dups.push(list[i]);
            } else {
                uniques.push(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return {dups: dups, uniques: uniques}
}

// count how many num in arr
function count(num, arr) {
    var count = 0;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == num) count++;
        if(count > 1) return count;
    }
    return count;
}
// check if num has not been checked
function notChecked(num, arr) {
    return (arr.indexOf(num) == -1) ? true : false;
}
```